# How to create a script that will run automatically every one hour and sends a curl request?

Tags: php, linux, curl, server, automation

I want to populate a hostoric database installed on a server. To do that I have to send multiple (curl)http requests on an endpoint changing the value of a certain field of a certain entity, also saved on a diffferent database. The problem is that I need to change the value of the field every hour for many days. I get it that people use cron jobs for this kind of task, but I need to know firstly in what language should I write the script preferrably(php, python, etc-with php being my personal preferred choice), or it does not simply matter and the important thing is to execute it via cron? Also what would the syntax for cron be in my scenario where I need to change the value every hour for say seven days?

Comment: This is at least 3 questions... however, for the scripting language, PHP/Python/whatever, it doesn't really matter from a technical perspective - just needs to be called on a Crontab, something like: `0 * * * * php /home/me/dosomething.php` (see [crontab ref](https://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference))

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are a lot of possibility to do cronjob, depends of your infrastructure. For example:

- in a web-hosting with cpanel/plesk you can call a script (php for example)
- you can also do cron by using user a starter, e.g. by creating a table on db with last execution on every user you can check the last execution and comparing it with actual time you can decide if start or not a scripts
- you can create a crontab for your server in caso of managed server or vps (e.g. https://crontab-generator.org/)
- you can use an online cron service. e.g. https://www.easycron.com/
- and so on...